# php echo table with while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I am creating a table and want it laid out a certain way and have to retrieve the data from the DB. I am trying to get it set up where it has the usernames across the top example...

```
 Jim     Chris     Allen    Rick
 7       8          4         5
```

my code looks like this and I have been messing around with it for hours and cant figure out why I cant get it set up how I want. Any help would be appreciated. Its a while loop.

```
   while ($pickresults= mysql_fetch_assoc($picksquery)) {
//first row                         
    echo '<th> '.$pickresults['username'].' </th> ';  
        echo ' <td> '.$pickresults['firstgame'].' </td> '; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should learn the HTML code for tables. Your code is putting a Table Header (`th`) next to a normal column item (`td`). You need to loop through the headers first then next row loop through the column items or build the strings to `echo` out.

```
$headers = $col = "";
while($pickresults= mysql_fetch_assoc($picksquery)){
    $headers .= "<th> {$pickresults['username']} </th>";
    $col .= "<td> {$pickresults['firstgame']} </td>";
}

echo "<table><tr>$headers</tr><tr>$col</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First collect table header and body, and **then** output them. The way you were doing, html was like this, I guess it's easy to see what is wrong with html

```
<th>name</th>
<td>value></td>
<th>another name</th>
<td>another value</td>
```

What you need is this:

```
$td = '';
$th = '';
while ($pickresults= mysql_fetch_assoc($picksquery)) {                      
    $th .= '<th> '.$pickresults['username'].' </th> ';  
    $td .= '<td> '.$pickresults['firstgame'].' </td> ';
}
echo '<table><tr>' . $th . '</tr><tr>' . $td . '</tr>' . '</table>';
```

Comment: Don't forget the enclosing `<tr>` around each row, or this won't be a valid `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is creating a TH then a TD and then a TH and then a TD etc.

This isn't how you create a table, you first need to make the four TH's and THEN you can make the four TD's.

Edit: Marko D has supplied the code to explain what I mean.

Comment: thanks a lot. This helps a lot. Saving the loop to an array is money.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write all usernames in `<th>`-tags.
I'd put it in an array first, and from the array into the table...

```
while ($pickresults= mysql_fetch_assoc($picksquery)) {

    $picked[]=$pickresults;

}

echo "<table><tr>"; // create table and 1st row

foreach ($picked as $pick) {

     echo "<th>{$pick['username']}</th>"; // create 1st line headers

}

echo "</tr><tr>"; // close 1st row and open 2nd

foreach ($picked as $pick) {

    echo "<td>{$pick['firstgame']}</td>"; // create 2nd line...

}

echo "</tr></table>"; // close 2nd row and table
```